# What is wrong with my node.js MongoDB 2dsphere find() call?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, geojson

In mongodb I have two collections to use that will help me answer the question `"Where are the cell towers in my state?"`

First collection was created from the Census data and it has a Polygon of the state boundary.

Second collection was created from downloading the OpenCellId database and importing it. "l" is the location coordinates key for the tower.

The javascript code needs to get the state and then print the towers in that state.

I've accomplished this using text (copy/paste) of the Polygon of Nevada in place of stateBounds variable in the `find()` call.

But when passing the exact same object instead of copy/paste, the `console.log("Tower found: %j", item);` call prints `"Tower found: [Circular]"`.

```
const mongoUrl  = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const hostname  = '127.0.0.1';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function(err, db){ 
    var towers  = db.collection('celltowers');
    var states  = db.collection('states');
    states.findOne({"properties.STUSPS": "NV"},function(err, item){
        getTowers(towers, item);
    }); 

});

function getTowers(celltowers, state) {
    var stateBounds = JSON.stringify(state, "geometry.coordinates");
    celltowers.find({l:{$geoWithin:{$geometry:{type: "Polygon", coordinates: stateBounds}}}}, function(err, item) {
        console.log("Tower found: %j", item);
    }); 
}
```

I need to use an geojson Polygon for `celltowers.find()`.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you tell what is the intention of this line in your code `JSON.stringify(state, "geometry.coordinates");` ? Can you add console and check value for `stateBounds`? Is it proper?

Comment: That JSON.stringify selects the properties of the geojson state. I needed just the coordinates and the address (if you will) to select is geometry.coordinates. By copying and pasting the result of that call and replacing stateBounds, the find() worked. So I think it is proper because the copy/paste worked.

Comment: The way you tried using Json. Stringy is not the right way. Please refer some documentation to know how you can get just a desired field from a Json object.

Comment: Using state['geometry.coordinates'] as well as JSON.stringify(state, "geometry.coordinates") results in the same problem (they both select the Polygon). I'm confused by the [Circular] error, what could be circular here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your db as below:

```
{
   //Some more fields as well
   geometry:{coordinates : [0,12]};
}
```

What you tried is in the query is not right. You tried giving the whole record i.e. `state` as `coordinates`. Instead you should give the value of the coordinates from the record in the find query.

This may solve your issue:-

```
function getTowers(celltowers, state) {
  var stateBounds = JSON.stringify(state);

  celltowers.find({l:{$geoWithin:{$geometry:
  {
     type: "Polygon", 
     coordinates: stateBounds.geometry.coordinates //Change is here.
  }
  }}}, function(err, item) 
  {
    console.log("Tower found: %j", item);
  });
}
```

You may refere [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#within-a-polygon) for more information on how to use.

Comment: The following line assigns just the coordinates of the state to the stateBounds variable passed into find(): var stateBounds = JSON.stringify(state, "geometry.coordinates");

Comment: Have you consoles and checked it? When I tried it gave me the whole object.

Comment: Yes. When pasting in what is printed to the console it works. Thats the kicker.